# Colourize text background of error lines in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, settings

I don't see red colours very well. I have a hard time seeing the faint wavy underlines below errors in Android Studio:

[image]

Is it possible to change the appearance of error lines to make them stick out more? Like, changing the background to dark blue or something. I searched the settings, but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change color and set any color from this path : 
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color scheme -> General -> Errors and Warnings -> Error

Here you can set whichever color you want for error and also change style as well like this :[image]